# Laravel API Passport Token

Tags: laravel, api

I have a question about laravel passport... I did the code and it is working very good, my question is about the token.

My friend has an mobile app which it will connect to my Laravel API... I already gave him a grant token my question is, do I have to give him a new token everytime that he wants to connect to the API? or just with that one is enough? one token and it works everytime?

I think that it works like this:

1. He wants to connect.
2. He passes the token to access to the API.
3. The API creates a response.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mobile application you should use password grant for Api protection. For password grant, the general concept is the API will give the app client the following parameters for accessing the auth client to get an **access token** and **refresh token**.

- grant_type: password
- client_id
- client_secret

When the user login in the mobile application, the mobile app will use the above parameters and also the user's username and password to request a user specific access token, this token usually will be active for 60 minutes, after 60 minutes, the app client need to use the refresh token to get a new access token.

**After getting the user access token, for the rest of your APP's api, the mobile client need to use this access token to access them.**

For Laravel Passport, you can check out the password grant document here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#creating-a-password-grant-client

To understand more about what password grant is check out this link:
https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/password-grant/

**Note:** From what I understand from your description, the grant type you are using is Client Credential Grant, this type is best for using system to system API authentication.